# How to set colspan and rowspan for ngx-datatable header in Angular?

Tags: angular, html-table, header, ngx-datatable

I am utilizing ngx-datatable and need 2-row header with colspan and rowspan.
I went through all documents and looked up on Google but can't find solutions.
Can somebody help me?

[image]

Comment: ngx-datatable rowspan colspan not supoorted here is open issue  https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/528 .

Comment: So there is no other alternative way to do this?